# date picker style issue with chrome versions :

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-material

Date picker style issue with chrome versions:

I use Angular version 1.4 and chrome version 62 it works fine.

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="reportParams.dateTo" md-max-date="reportParams.maxDate" ng-change="reportParams.setReportParams()" required></md-datepicker>
```

But when I update chrome version to version 63 the date picker shows wrong : 
[image]

Comment: I suggest you post this on the issues for AngularJS Material's Github repo.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with chrome version 63